# installing gedit in linux with python 2.7.3

Tags: python, linux, gedit

I have tried to install 2 versions of gedit in linux with python version of 2.7.3

gedit 3.8.1 and gedit 3.7.6 both come with error when i use ./configure
"configure: error: no suitable Python interpreter found"

can I know which version of gedit to install to suit with my python version?

Comment: `configure` also tells you which Python version it was looking for.

Comment: im new to Linux (installed it few hours ago), sorry if my question is not that clear. when i Type python -V it shows that it is installed with python 2.7.3, when I tried to install gedit 3.8.1 and gedit 3.7.6 it comes up with a configuration error, should I install something first?

Comment: what version of linux are you using? You might just be able to use a package manager thingy or `apt-get`. I don't think this is the right place for this question by the way...

Comment: it says that i need python interpreter with version >= 3.2.3, what version of gedit should I need for python version 2.7.3? Im using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: so you need to install that then. There are some pretty big differences between python 2 and 3

Comment: what flavor linux are you using? Ubuntu? Something else? There are many shortcuts for installing things but it depends on what you are actually running

Comment: Im using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know gedit is installed by default. Try type `gedit` in a terminal and see if it opens.

alternatively in a terminal type `sudo apt-get install gedit` This will install Ubuntu's current favorate version of gedit.

In either case this wont get you the latest version but unless you are super keen on the latest version for some reason then don't worry about it.

If you do want the latest version you need to install python3 first in which case this should help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3